# How do I remove the "wrench" button on the balloon tooltip?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-shell, windows-explorer, notifyicon

I want to hide the wrench button on the balloon tooltip

Does anyone know how? Is it possible to disable/remove the **wrench button** next to the close button on the balloon tooltip in the system tray that is being called from `System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon`?

[image: Balloon Tooltip]

Please help 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Context....? What wrench from what tooltip?

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? What system tray?

Comment: It is an option to open windows notification window. I added a notifyicon to my windows form so that it would display a balloon tip in the system tray. This balloon tip has an option that looks like a monkey-wrench. I wish to remove it from my balloon tooltip.

Comment: @SimpleCoder I think [this](http://i.imgur.com/xsFEi.png) is the one he's talking about. but I'm just guessing here.

Comment: are you using the System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon ? then please add this to the question. not such a bad question btw

Comment: but I guess there is no way, because it is handled by the explorer. perhaps changing the notification settings of the explorer will help, but then the wrench will disappear always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I do not think this is possible. The explorer process which is responsible for desktop icons and the task bar is responsible for controlling the notification area as well. You may use a different object than `NotifyIcon` to show notification icons. I'd recommend you to use [DevComponents](http://DevComponents.com) if you would like to see similar objects

Sorry about that,

 I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: @blumonde No problems at all, Glad I could help :)