# I'm using a BalloonTip but why in the Balloon info message i also have the tools/settings icon how can remove it?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void SetBalloonTip()
        {
            notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation;
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Test";
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "test";
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
        }

        private void Form1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(30000);
        }
```

The settings/tools(Notification Area Icons) icon if i l cick on it i get into the Notification Area Icons. Anyway to make that the Balloon will be without this ?

EDIT**

Here is an image of the balloon and what i mean. I mean the icon looks like a wrench:
I want to remove the wrench to disable it.

[image]

Comment: Hard to guess what "tools/setting icon" might mean.  Sounds like ToolTipIcon.Info, the one you asked for.

Comment: Updated my question added also an image with what i mean.

Comment: Just realised what you meant. It's not easily possible as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037168/how-do-i-remove-the-wrench-button-on-the-balloon-tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The balloon tip decorations are drawn by Windows, there isn't anything that you can do in your program to suppress them.  Windows draws an X glyph in the upper right corner to give the user a target to click on to dismiss the tip.  And the wrench glyph next to it invokes the configuration popup window that lets the user decide which icons are displayed and which are hidden.

Windows gives the user the tools he needs to make these icons effective and prevent them from flooding the taskbar.  A significant problem in early versions of Windows, the notification area is very popular with programmers and they all think that their icon is the most important one.  That did not work out well.

Feature, not a bug.